# return joins as json with postgres 10

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following structure

`task` -> hasMany `links` -> hasOne `user`

what I would like to see returned is

```
task.id | [
   { linkType: 'foo', userid:1, taskid:1, 
        user : { name: 'jon', lastname: 'smith'}, 
   ... ]
```

being a sql noob, I have managed to get so far as this

```
select task.id, json_agg(links.*) as links from task 
    left outer join links on task.id = links.taskid 
    join "user" on "user".id = links.userid 
    group by task.id ;
```

which gives me

```
task.id | [{ linkType: 'foo', userid:1, taskid:1}, ... ]
```

but obviously missing the user

I'm kinda stuck now on how to add the `user` property to each of the link array items

I've read several documents but they always seem to stop at the first join

the schema design is

```
create table task (id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY)
create table "user" (id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, username text)

create table links (taskid integer references task (id), userid integer references "user" (id) );
```

Comment: "but obviously missing the user".  The user is in the JSON.

Comment: not sure what you mean - there is no "user" property in the json, just the properties of the "links" table.

Comment: Could you please post the table structure of the `task`, `links` and `user` tables? Thanks.

Comment: I've added the basic structure , thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not reference the table structure you provided, because `"user"` has a `name` and a `lastname` column in the former and a single `username` column in the latter, but you did provide enough information to give an answer. I am using the two-column user, because it allows to show how to construct nested JSON objects.

```
SELECT task.id, 
       json_agg(
         json_build_object(
           'linkType', 'foo',
           'taskid', links.taskid, 
           'userid', links.userid, 
           'user', json_build_object('name', u.name, 'lastname', u.lastname)
         )
       ) AS links 
  FROM task 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN links ON task.id = links.taskid 
  JOIN "user" u ON u.id = links.userid 
 GROUP BY task.id;
```

The general problem of building json objects with the appropriate key values is discussed in [this excellent DBA.SE answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg). I have adopted what is listed there as solution number 3 because I think it is the most flexible and the most readable. Your tastes might differ.

Comment: whilst this works, and is indeed the answer, I was wondering if we could push the boundaries a little bit .. ;) What if both the link table and the user table has a number of fields - it seems inefficient  to have to type out all those fields individually.  functions like to_jsonb(row) seem to provide this functionality, but without the option of adding extra properties

Comment: The linked answer at DBA.SE and its comments show several examples. The problem with some implicit ways of building JSON objects is that you lose the keys when the values come from different tables, so you must specify them in one way or another.